# How to Register a Gstreamer Plugin?

Tags: plugins, gstreamer, raspberry-pi

I was trying to install a gstreamer plugin in my Raspberry Pi.
I have downloaded the Gstreamer plugin from a repository, then I build the binaries. After building I did a

`sudo make install` to install the gstreamer openmax plugin.

But the plugin (gst-openmax) that have hardware decoder elements(omxh264dec etc) are not being listed in gst-inspect.

I think it is because I have not register the plugin ?
How do I register this plugin ?

I have gone through the code and found a function called `plugin_init()` inside which they have written code to register the plugin. How to invoke this function ?
I tried setting the environmental variables such as `GST_PLUGIN_PATH, GST_OMX_CONFIG_DIR, LD_LIBRARY_PATH etc` But that too didnt work.
How to Register this open max plugin so that I can use it in different pipelines ?

Answer (score 3):

To get gstreamer to detect your plugin (ie the .dll or .so file) you just need to put it in the plugin directory. You don't need to invoke any function calls such as plugin_init etc. Gstreamer will automatically call it if it detects a plugin in the plugin directory.

Comment: thank you james for answering.. What you said is correct. I realized my problem, I was giving wrong path to config file